# With jquery remove both a span and the next 2 characters

Tags: jquery, volusion

I am trying to remove an element from a volusion page where I don't have access to large parts of the code.  I can remove some stuff using jquery, but there are elements outside of the span I can't get rid of.

```
<span class="PageText_L329n">Quantity in Stock</span>:6<meta itemprop='availability' content='InStock'>
```

I can use

```
$("span.PageText_L329n").remove();
```

to get rid of the "Quantity in Stock" section, but the :6 doesn't have its own container.  The parent div that this is sitting in has a lot of other stuff in it I don't want to touch.  Is there a way to remove this span and the following several characters?  Or separately select the :6 and remove it without a container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/tUBxc/1

## **JS**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var text = $('.PageText_L329n')[0].nextSibling;
    $(text).remove();
});
```

## **New Js**  by [user2592238](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2592238/user2592238)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body:contains('Quantity in Stock')").each(function () {
        var text = $(this).text();
        text = text.replace("Quantity in Stock:", "");
        $(this).text(text);
    });
});
```

Comment: Nope, that didn't remove anything.

Comment: Yea, it works there, but when I put it into they actual page, the same thing doesn't happen.

Comment: weird, it is removing it in firefox, but not in chrome

Comment: you are not adding <span class="PageText_L329n"></span> in the page

Comment: Thats weird.  It shows up in firefox, but in chrome there is no span there.

Comment: check span again it doesn't show in any of my browsers(i.e,moz,chrome)

Comment: I mande a small change to 
$("body:contains('Quantity in Stock')").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    text = text.replace("Quantity in Stock:", "");
    $(this).text(text);
}); and it works